# Access top level dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, jinja2

I'm struggling in Jinja2, it seems I just can't figure out a way to access the top level parameter inside a template.

Let's assume I pass a dictionary like this:

```
{
  "entity1": {"whatever":"smth"},
  "entity2": "cool"
}
```

Please note that the entites are not cohesive (edit: and thus is absolutely not a collection), I use entities for readability but it's very unstructured data.

The goal would be to iterate through all of the entities. But I can't figure out a way to grab `toplevel.items()`, I only can walk through `entity1.items()`.

I might have missed something in the docs but I'm running out of options, tried pretty much every keyword.

Comment: Why don't you pass a dictionary like: `{"entities": {...}}` instead?

Comment: The main purpose is to have the highest possible abstraction, in order for my template to be reusable in many CI/CD pipelines.
This is what I am doing right now.
Also note, I'll precise in the question, that the entites are not cohesive, I use entities for readability but it's very unstructured data.
It might not be doable to reach the top level, in which case I'll adapt.

Comment: @Mumrau the technical answer is in jonrshrape's comment - if you want to have a collection of entities in your template's context, you have to pass them as nested dict (or list or whatever). Ry's question is still quite sensible nonetheless...

Comment: It is not a collection.
It's a dict with nested dicts, and nested dicts and nested dicts, etc.....
What if I want an abstract template that formats the data as text in the way I want it to be? It takes whatever dict and structures it the way you want to, number of spaces, tabs, tags, etc.
It could very well just format the dict as a text dict in a file (it wouldn't solve any business case, and there are other ways to achieve that, but it could be a great exercise).

Comment: What you're describing is basically rewriting a templating language, though, instead of *using one*.

Comment: ...
It does use one.
Anyway, forget about it. The question was dead simple: "Can I access the top level item of the parameters?" If I can't, cool, I'll open a ticket and so be it, I'll make it work.

Comment: @Mumrau: did you ever get around to opening a ticket ? or did you find a solution ? similar issue here: I get some JSON with a list of objects from somewhere and need to use it as jinja2 template input; don't know how to access the top level list to iterate over its objects; unless there is some other way, I'll have to inject a top level key with the list as value...

Comment: @ssc I gave up and adapted....